# Incompatible Packages w/ 26.3 and MELPA

Tags: package-repositories, emacs26

I know I must be missing something simple, but I've recently upgraded my Linux OS to Mate 20.04.  As a result, my version of emacs is Emacs 26.3. I'm now running into incompatibility issues with MELPA packages.

I get numerous errors of the form:

`gnus-notes         20210103.2050 incompat   melpa      Keep handy notes...`

gnus-notes is an incompatible package.

```
     Status: Incompatible because it depends on Emacs 27.1.
    Archive: melpa
    Version: 20210103.2050
     Commit: 8cacba653f8912355d45847c5e5376eb83e6898f
    Summary: Keep handy notes of read Gnus articles with helm and org
   Requires: emacs-27.1, bbdb-3.1, helm-3.1, hydra-0.13.0, org-8.3, s-0.0, lv-0.0,
               async-1.9.1
   Homepage: https://github.com/deusmax/gnus-notes
```

Is there an archive repo I should be using?  A setting for my init.el file?

Comment: That package simply requires a newer emacs version. Isn't the status line clear enough? You could poke the referenced github page for an older release working with your older emacs.

Comment: The status line is clear, what wasn't clear to me was a work around that doesn't require upgrading.  The package manager I'm most familiar with, apt, take one's version into account when querying a repository.  I was hoping that there was a similar ability with melpa.   I find it hard to believe the repo only works flawlessly with the latest version of emacs...